How to convert a JSON into a TimeSpan c#
I'm having trouble converting a json into a timeSpan in C#, I have different json. Here are a few examples:
{
  ‘seconds’: 60
}
{
  ‘hours’: 11
}
{
  ‘years: 5
}

If you have any ideas I'd be grateful
Thanks
I'm looking to dynamically create timeSpans based on the returned Json.
For example :
As input:
{
  ‘seconds’: 60
}

=> Output:
new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 60, 0 )


despite your json having invalid quoting-characters, what have you tried already? Shouldn't be that hard to read these three values from a JSON (otherwise goofgle for "read value from JSON using C', I bet you get hundreds of answers). So where specifically are you stuck?

What you have is not valid JSON.  You'd either need to correct the source of the data to produce valid JSON (which you could then deserialize into an object in C#) or you'd need to write your own string parsing logic to extract data from this otherwise custom format.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

I tried to create a generic GetAll() function that would convert all the types present in the database (day, month, year, hour...). I can't see how to convert this string containing a json into a timeSpan. I can't change my Db, the data is stored as a varchar.

JSON uses double quotes (") to wrap property names and string values i.e. {"seconds": 60}. Please show us what you have tried including any errors and actual output

@KryZoh: "I can't see how to convert this string containing a json into a timeSpan." - Break apart the problem into smaller steps.  Forget about the Timespan for a moment.  First you need to extract your values from this string.  As mentioned already, this string is not JSON.  So unless you can correct the source of the data to be valid JSON then you can't use JSON-parsing tools.  It would be up to you to parse these values from this custom data format.  For that you can try a variety of methods on strings (split, substring, etc.), or perhaps regular expressions.

How does your json look for a timespan of for example "1 day, 2 hours and 60 seconds"?

Ok thanks a lot, i will try to first convert my string into json.

Sorry, I made a mistake. In my database, here's an example of the format: {
"seconds": 60
}. I only looked at the viewer... So here is my data once retrieved from my object: "{\r\n  "hours": 11\r\n}"

But do you have combinations such as { "seconds": 60, "days": 5 } 

@KryZoh: If you do have valid JSON then you can parse data from it by "deserializing" that JSON in C#.  There are many examples of how to do this, your favorite search engine can help you get started.

@Magnus No i don't have combinaison.

Using TimeSpans that include "years" and "months" is not logical since it doesn't account for different days in different months. It totally defeats its intended purpose: "Durations of days or less".

Create your own class do deserialize to. Then convert that to a TimeSpan.
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        var json =
            """
            { "seconds": 60, "days": 5 }
            """;

        var timeSpan = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyTimeSpan>(json, options)?.ToTimeSpan();
    }

    public class MyTimeSpan
    {
        public int Seconds { get; set; }
        public int Minutes { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
        public int Days { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan ToTimeSpan() => new(Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    }
}


using System;
using System.Text.Json;
public class JsonTimeSpanConverter
{
public TimeSpan ConvertJsonToTimeSpan(string json)
{
    var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    var root = jsonDocument.RootElement;

    int days = root.TryGetProperty("days", out var daysElement) ? daysElement.GetInt32() : 0;
    int hours = root.TryGetProperty("hours", out var hoursElement) ? hoursElement.GetInt32() : 0;
    int minutes = root.TryGetProperty("minutes", out var minutesElement) ? minutesElement.GetInt32() : 0;
    int seconds = root.TryGetProperty("seconds", out var secondsElement) ? secondsElement.GetInt32() : 0;
    int milliseconds = root.TryGetProperty("milliseconds", out var millisecondsElement) ? millisecondsElement.GetInt32() : 0;

    return new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
}
}

The JsonTimeSpanConverter class contains a method ConvertJsonToTimeSpan that takes a JSON string as input and extracts the relevant time components (days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds) to create a TimeSpan object. The code uses the System.Text.Json namespace for parsing JSON data.
